# R package with Rcpp and CMake (Windows)

Tags: r, cmake, rcpp

I'm using CMake as a build tool to create C++ shared library with Rcpp. To trigger CMake while invoking `R CMD INSTALL` command the top `configure` script need to look something like this:

```
rm -rf _builds
cmake -H. -B_builds
cmake --build _builds
...
```

Such approach works nicely on Linux and Mac OS, but not on Windows machine.

What version of CMake expected in `configure`:

- windows native cmake
- cygwin cmake

What generator do I need to use:

- `Unix Makefiles` (cygwin)
- `MSYS Makefiles` (native)
- `MinGW Makefiles` (native)

#### SSCCE

- https://github.com/forexample/rcpp-test

Comment: I'll file that under "your problem" as R (and Rcpp) provide a robust, tested, documented, and largely error-free toolchain.  If you need a different one, well, then you need to build it.

Comment: Your external link is by definition not "self contained."

Comment: The R build toolchain supports calling an executable script `configure` on platforms ending in x or X.  On 'doze, you're on your own.

Comment: Try it, and it will break dual-arch builds on Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69025/discussion-between-dirk-eddelbuettel-and-ruslo).

Answer (score 8):

Leave all `Makefile` files (`Makefile.win` for windows) empty:

```
all:
```

Put CMake build instructions into `configure` (`configure.win` for windows):

```
cmake -H. -B_builds
cmake --build _builds
```

Such approach works nice for me on Linux, Mac and Windows (native `cmake` with `Visual Studio` generator). Note that it's probably not compatible with [cran](http://cran.r-project.org/) and windows build need to be tuned to compile different architectures (see `R_ARCH`) but it works locally and fit my needs.

- [Example](https://github.com/forexample/r-cmake)